# HTML5 video tag called inside ng-if with false condition or in ng-repeat with empty list

Tags: angularjs, html, html5-video

I have a list of videos that can change dinamically server-side; and I want them to appear dinamically on the page, using the HTML5 video tag. If the list is empty, I want the `ul` tag to show a "no videos" message.

EDIT: I just noticed that it tries to call that wrong link also when the list is not empty. He first tries to call that, and then calls the correct link(s).

My code is as follows. EDIT: as you can see, I'm using the video-js and the videojs-contrib-hls plugins, I don't know if it is relevant:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.8/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <ul ng-if="myVideos.length" ng-cloak>
        <li ng-repeat="myVideo in myVideos" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="videoContainer">
                <p>{{myVideo.user_id}}</p>
                <p>{{myVideo.url}}</p>
                <video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="159" height="110" data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="{{myVideo.url}}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
                </video>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-if="!myVideos.length" ng-cloak>
        <li>
            <div class="videoContainer">
            No videos to show.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <script src="js/lib/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script><!-- Angular is v1.2.30 -->
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.10.8/video.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

myScript.js:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect(document.location.origin);
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {  
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    },

    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          if (callback) {
            callback.apply(socket, args);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  };
});

function MyCtrl($scope, $http, socket, $sce) {

    $scope.videos = [];
    $scope.current_monitor = {name:"", sourceIP:""};

    var httpRequest = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/getVideos'        
    }).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.videos = data['videos'];
        $scope.videos.forEach(function(val){
            val.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val.url);
        });
        updateMainMonitor();
    });
    socket.on('refreshVideos', function (data) {
        $scope.videos = data['videos'];
        $scope.videos.forEach(function(val){
            val.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val.url);
        });
        updateMainMonitor();
    });

    updateMainMonitor = function(){
        if($scope.videos && $scope.videos.length){
            $scope.current_monitor = $scope.videos[0];
        } else {
            $scope.current_monitor.name = "No video to show";
            $scope.current_monitor.sourceIP = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, if the list is empty when I load the page, I can see in the console the error:

```
GET http://myIp:8080/%7B%7BmyVideo.url%7D%7D 404 Not found
```

Why is it doing that? I know it's just a console error, but I'm new to Angular and it makes me think there is something wrong somewhere. How can I prevent it?

Comment: could yu show us your js ?

Comment: it's your html not your js

Comment: @DMCISSOKHO whooops, right.

Comment: It seems it's more an http request issue. Try to access directly `http://myIp:8080/%7B%7BmyVideo.url%7D%7D` ouside your app

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is trying to render the pre-compiled src of "`{{myVideo.url}}`" on page load. I'd suggest you read about Angular [data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) and try the following with `ng-src`:

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="159" height="110" data-setup="{}">
     <source ng-src="{{myVideo.url}}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

This is the same reason you would want to [use `ng-src` in an `img` tag](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Answer (score 0):

The tag video doesn't copile in real time for security

For example, if you compile

```
document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0]
```

The result is empty. So if you compile

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]
```

The result is a button (domElement).

Comment: Thank you really much! Although this looks more like an explanation of the problem, rather than a solution. Do you have any idea for a workaround?